# How to pass a Boolean value to another script before closing window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I have two windows, each has their own cs script: One login window and one main window, in the login window I have a boolean `bool keepLogin` which is set to `true` or `false` whenever the user ticket a "Remember me" checkbox.

Now after the login is completed, the login window closes using `this.Close()` and opens the main window using `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow()` and `mainWindow.Show()`.

I assume this also closes the CS script attached to the login window, so how can I pass on the `bool keepLogin` to the CS of mainWindow so it can be used there?

Comment: Add a public property to the MainWindow and set it e.g. like `var mainWindow = new MainWindow { MyBooleanProperty = someBooleanValue }; mainWindow.Show();`

Comment: Note that "CS script" is a specific thing, and isn't what you're talking about here. Perhaps you're referring to a different `class`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I am working in XAML windows (If that's the correct way to describe it) both having a `.xaml.cs` file attached to them, so thats what I was referring to. Might have been that I do mean a `class`, but I have no idea to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** using Clemens method in the comment on the post:

"Add a public property to the MainWindow and set it e.g. like var `mainWindow = new MainWindow { MyBooleanProperty = someBooleanValue }; mainWindow.Show();`"

Comment: You can mark the answer is the Preferred One, making it easily visible for everybody.